# Insert formula in one cell using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I know this topic was already asked and I tried to copy on how to insert a formula in one cell, however, I got an error in my vba code.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
ws.Range("C9").Formula = "=CountIf(wsRD.Range(C & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row, ""Event"")"   'CountIf(wsRD.Range("C" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row, "Event") 'count(Search("Event", wsRD.Range("C" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row, 1))
```

I need to insert a formula in ws.Range("C9"), in which, it summarizes the count of the cell that have a value of "Event" in wsRD.Range("C" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row. May I know what's the problem in my code? Appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Comment: You are combining vba syntax with excel syntax. When you are inside the quotes, use excel syntax

Comment: Are you wanting to count every instance of `Event` from `C10` to the last row?

Comment: yes, I need to count every instance of Event from C10 to last row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get rid of the `LRow` variable and just drop it in your equation if you wanted to.

```
Dim LRow as Long
LRow = ws.Range("C" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

ws.Range("C9").Formula = "=COUNTIF(C10:C" & LRow & ", ""Event"")"
```

Comment: I am using the same instance of `ws` that you used. Not sure if the `LRow` should be looking to `ws` or `wsRD` as you only showed one line of your code. I'm sure you can apply the above to your code tho

Comment: I am using different sheet in my example, ws sheet is to put the value of the count no. of event. While the wsRD sheet, is where all the data located. I need to count the event in the wsRD sheet.

Comment: Well just change that part

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this could be the correct answer

```
ws.Select
LRow = ws.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("C9").FormulaLocal = "=COUNTIF(C10:C" & LRow & ";""Event"")"
```

So basically, I used FormulaLocal to write the formula the same way I write it in Excel, then, because the formula must be a big String, I separated it in 2 strings, put the value LRow, and used & & to concatenate

Comment: Best answer in my opinion. .FormulaLocal solved my problems!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone, like myself, wants to put advanced Excel formulas inside cells referring to Table functions like ByCol and alike, the solution should be to 'stuff' these into cells using .Formula2Local, instead.

```
Sub Populate_Formulas_Click()
    Dim Formula As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 2               ' Start in column B
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each Formula In Range("B13:M13")                              ' Source of Formulatext, added as Value and prepended with a single quote
            Sheets("Report").Select
            Cells(56, i).Formula2Local = Mid(Formula.Value2, 1)       ' Copy formula, after the first single quote prefix it with "="
            i = i + 1
    Next Formula
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Best of Luck