# Trying to use Countif in a formula

Tags: excel, vba, countif

How to use countif in a formula

I did some research on google and other forums but did not find a solution. it's not a syntax error so it's not my double quotes that is the issue. the error is run time 1004, application defined or object defined error.

```
Cells(a, 1).Formula = "=Countif(Range(cells(" & a & ",7),cells(" & a & ",21))),""a"""
```

In the first case, a is 5, so i want it to scan columns g through u in row 5, count any occurrences of the letter 'a'

Expected a number counting all the occurences of "a" in a row, instead im getting a 1004 error

just a note to the moderators, on my last post, i was demoted i guess for asking a dumb question. how can i get that fixed as the thread is closed.

Comment: You are aware that you are using `Range` and `Cells` in a worksheet formula? Are you not looking to use `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf`? Or are you trying to populate a cell with a formula?

Comment: to  populate a cell with a formula.

Comment: please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52671561/insert-formula-in-one-cell-using-vba?rq=1). This should help.

Answer (score 1):

So based on your response in the comments section I think you are looking to use:

```
Sub PutFormulaInCell()

Dim a As Long
a = 5

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Cells(a, 1).Formula = "=Countif(G" & a & ":U" & a & "," & """a"")"
End With

End Sub
```

Right now you have mixed up VBA and Excel syntax's resulting in a 1004 error.

Comment: yup, that did the trick. and so simple. and i see where i made the error, won't happen again.

Comment: Glad it helped @DanM, please accept as answer. Much appreciated